# Is it okay to modify the SQL Server Reporting Services' web.config file?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, configuration

I need to implement custom security for SQL Server Reporting Services. To do this, I would like to add some configuration into the web.config of the SSRS' Reports Server web application.

My question is - is it safe to do this? Might my custom configuration be overrun by some SSRS process? Or by an automatic update to the SSRS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

[MSDN gives examples of when to change stuff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156453%28SQL.90%29.aspx#SpecifyingVirtualServerName)

As for updates, we've patched our installations with the same setting (and some others) and they didn't break. Given the number of potential legitimate changes to RS config files, I'd say a patch should not break it.